# How to place text view on right side of image view without overlapping it and covering whole width in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to place text view on the right side of image view. While I am able to do that, I am facing problem when I give match parent to text view. I want the text to cover remaining area, but when I use match parent, it overlaps the image view on the left.
Here is my code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"

        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/effective_warnings_card_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_unavailable_image"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_text"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.TSBApp20.Body.Regular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="aggfgffh"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <!--            <ImageView-->
    <!--                android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"-->

    <!--                        android:layout_width="48dp"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_height="48dp"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_default"-->
    <!--                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_unavailable_image"-->
    <!--                        android:importantForAccessibility="no"-->
    <!--                        android:focusable="false"-->
    <!--                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
    <!--                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
    <!--                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
    <!--                        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"-->
    <!--                            />-->
    <!--            <TextView-->
    <!--                android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_text"-->
    <!--                style="@style/TextAppearance.TSBApp20.Body.Regular"-->
    <!--                android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="afafafaffafa"-->
    <!--                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
    <!--                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"-->
    <!--                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"-->
    <!--                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"-->
    <!--                />-->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the added image you can see text covering the image with black layout. How to achieve this ? [image]

Comment: Share your UI which you want to achive.

Comment: @MehulKabaria this is part of card layout which is used elsewhere , so couldn't share whole thing. Basically I need image and text side by side,like text on right of image, with the whole in a card view. And use it in a adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `0dp` to your `TextView`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:focusable="false"

            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/effective_warnings_card_text"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_unavailable_image"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.TSBApp20.Body.Regular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="aggfgffh"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove             `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"` from `TextView`

Also remove             `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/effective_warnings_card_text"` from `ImageView`

Set `0dp` width to `TextView`

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:focusable="false"

            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_unavailable_image"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/effective_warnings_card_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.TSBApp20.Body.Regular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="aggfgffh"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/effective_warnings_card_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```